# "Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled" error when sending request to backend api endpoint with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, mern

My folder structure is like this

```
gamezone
  -.next
  -app

     -api //backend
        -signup
           -route.js
         -login
            -route.js
   
      -login //frontend
         -page.jsx
       -signup
          -page.jsx

  -components
      //all components
```

I have  user schema named "user"

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    img: {
        type: String
    }
})
const User = mongoose.model.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User
```

and importing it on backend "signup/route.js"file.

```
import { connect } from '@/db/db'
import User from '@/models/userModels'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
connect();

export async function POST(req) {
    const { username, email, password } = await req.json()
    const newUser = new User({
        name: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    const result = await newUser.save();
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "user registerd", result })
}
```

When i start the server with

```
npm run dev
```

for first time and send the request for on 'localhost:3000/api/signup' with username,email and password with postman or thunder client it save the user on database and works totally fine. but when i visit to 'localhost:3000' with browser and then ( it may noted that there is no error on my terminal or browser console) send request with frontend or postman it gives me this error

`` error Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled. ``

I want to fix this error

Comment: mongoose.model.User or  mongoose.models.User ?